# Calling report with oracle report builder 12

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I need to call an other report with parameters from my report by report builder 12. But it seems to be, there is no button for calling an other one. Is there any way to call second report from the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First stop the report server. (OC4J instance also for 10g)
2. Search for CGICMD.DAT file in Developersuite home. (for 10g It’s located at  folder. And for 11g D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\WLS_REPORTS\applications\reports_11.1.2\configuration)
3. Open the CGICMD.DAT file and go to bottom line and add the bellow lines and modify as your value.

   ; hrs: userid=test/password@orcl server=rep_server desformat=pdf destype=cache paramform=no %*
   (Where first userid, report server name, report destination format, destination type and no parameter form.)
4. Save and close the file.
5. Now open the report which will have the link.
6. Select the data field and press F11 to go code editor and add the bellow code before
   return (true);
   SRW.SET_HYPERLINK('http://SERVER_NAME:8889/reports/rwservlet?hrs+report='D:\ID_CARD_ALL.rep+EMPID='||:EMP_ID);
   (Change the report server url as you have, report name and parameter if you have)

Compile and save the reports.

Now Run the report server and run your report…

LOVE U SETAREH

Answer (score 2):

Such a functionality is called *drill down* (so that you'd be able to research it yourself, if you want).

In the *old* Reports 6i, you could have done it by creating a button. In modern Reports version, you'll have to use a **hyperlink** - it can be found within the "Web" settings, and looks like this:

```
http://your_server:port/reports/rwservlet?userid=scott/tiger@orcl+report=your_report.rdf+
destype=cache+desformat=html+par_deptno=&deptno
```

Interesting part is the very end of it, which shows how to pass a parameter from *this report* (which contains the `&deptno` value) to *another report* (which expects deptno value to be passes into the `par_deptno` parameter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and its very helpful. Is ther any way to encrypt url for hiding user, password and parameters’s value? Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I know that - as of Developer Suite 10g (which we still use), there's the **CGICMD.DAT**, stored on the IAS (application server). It is a file which contains KEY-VALUE pairs, where KEY represents report you're calling (its name can be anything you want; we keep it the same as the .RDF file name), while the VALUE contains server name, username/password combination, the RDF file name, destype, desformat info, as well as parameter's *placeholders*. So, when calling a report, we use the *KEY* which hides everything. I don't know if Reports 12c have that too.

Comment: Thank you very much and appreciate for taking your time